# Dagger 2 injection of fields inside classes other than Activities

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have a class other than an Activity with injected fields :

```
public Class1 extends Class2 {
  @Inject A a;
}

public Class2 extends Class3 {
  @Inject B b;
}

public Class3 {
  @Inject C c;
}
```

And I am providing Class1 like this:

```
@Provides
Class1 provideClass1(){
   return new Class1();
}
```

My question : when providing `Class1` will `Dagger` inject `B` and `C` at the level of the super class? Or should I use constructor injection and call super inside the constructors?

Answer (score 2):

Activity, Fragment, and Service are ideal sites for property injection because you have no control over their constructor and their instantiation is handled by the Android OS.

For the rest of your classes, constructor injection gives much more control and makes it easier to unit test. When writing a unit test, you simply pass in the test doubles you want when you are initialising the system under test. You also make it easier to write immutable classes fulfilling Effective Java item 15.

As for your other question, Dagger 2 is smart enough to inject properties in a super class. In other words, if you have a `ConcreteService` extends `BaseService` and you call `component.inject(this)` inside `ConcreteService` Dagger 2 will know to inject the properties of `BaseService` if they are annotated correctly.

However, in your example you have a mix of property injection (the `@Inject` annotations inside `Class1` and `Class2`) and constructor injector (the `@Provides` method for `Class1` which simply uses the constructor). This is not enough to have all the properties in the super classes of `Class1` to be injected because you have specified the medium of provision of `Class1` to be a simple call to the constructor. On the other hand, if you obtained the instance of `Class1` through a component (through provision methods) or through requesting injection on a class which has a `@Inject` annotated `Class1` property then you would get a fully-formed instance.